# Ubuntu 20.04 completely free freeze/hanges minutes after login

Tags: 20.04, kernel, freeze

I just clean install ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop...

But approximately 10 min after login my GUI freeze/hangs completely mouse and keyboard doesn't work, i have to press down the power button to restart the laptop.

have tried using kernel 5.4 it work but freeze for few seconds and pick up again and it repeat that frequently but never freeze completely.

have search through for solution but none worked:
My kernel version: Linux 5.11.7-051107-generic x86_64

my laptop details:
System Information
Manufacturer: HP
Product Name: HP Notebook
Ram: 4gb
Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3700 @ 1.60GHz × 4
Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 405 (BSW)

Graphics:
Device-1: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-.E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx
Integrated Graphics
vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: i915 resolution: 1366x768~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 405 (BSW) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6
direct render: Yes

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Can we have the output of inxi -Fxzd added to your question please?

Comment: As you can read on this announcement 5.11 is not for LTS version of Ubuntu. https://www.tipsonunix.com/2021/02/how-to-install-linux-kernel-5-11-in-ubuntu-linux-mint/#:~:text=Linus%20Torvalds%20announced%20the%20Linux,improvements%2C%20and%20better%20hardware%20support.

Comment: Its a tough one to answer as clearly its a kernel level issue..

Disable all power savings modes is what I'd start with.

Comment: @SimonBanks which of the output should i add as i can see here the output is quite much .. i guess you are pointing to graphics details??

Comment: @David have tried with different kernel ranging from 5.4 to 5.11 but i still have the freeze issue

Comment: 21.04 is released on April 22, maybe better luck then.

Comment: @David I believe there is a fix for this ..

Comment: Lubuntu is for low powered systems. https://lubuntu.me/

Comment: See if adequate swap memory is available

Comment: Thank you @Oppili ... i have adequate swap memory ... however have been able to solve the issue ..

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve this problem by editing with sudo privilege /etc/default/grub

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and i change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

from:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

adding two additional parameters "`intel_idle.max_cstate=1`"

and like that the freeze problem is solved, i hope this answer help someone.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Has this fix been successful since you posted this (Apr 12, 2021)?